# Text Mining - most common words, normalized

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I am a researcher and have about 17,000 free-text documents of which around 30-40% are associated with my outcome. Is there an open-source tool I can use to determine the most common words (or even phrases, but not necessary) that are associated with the outcome, normalizing for the frequency of words that are already occurring? All of the documents are written by health care workers, so it will be important to normalize since there will be technical language across both documents and also would want to screen out words like "the", "it", etc.

What I am trying to do is build a tool using regular expressions or NLP that will then use these words to identify the outcome based on new documents. I'm not planning on spending a huge amount of time customizing an NLP tool, so something with reasonable accuracy is good enough.

I know SAS, SQL (am using postgreSQL), and Python, but could potentially get by in R. I haven't done any NLP before. Is there any software I could use that doesn't have too steep of a learning curve? Thanks!

Comment: My video series shows how to do that using RapidMiner (FOSS, GUI): http://vancouverdata.blogspot.ca/2010/11/text-analytics-with-rapidminer-loading.html

Comment: `R` is a good tool for this. If you can post a Q with some sample data and a snippet of your desired outcome then you'll likely get some code to help you with it. Have a search of SO using `[r] [text-mining]` and you'll probably find code that you can easily adapt to your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

```
  tool I can use to determine the most common words... 
  ... so something with reasonable accuracy is good enough.
```

I suggest try using unix text tools first. 
From coursera [Natural Language Processing](https://class.coursera.org/nlp/class/index) course Word Tokenization Lesson,  Youtube link is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkImc447pZo&list=PL8FFE3F391203C98C&index=4). A simple tutorial [here](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~pary/texttools.pdf).

We use [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29), [uniq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) and [sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28Unix%29) for this purpose. If you used unix text tools before, this is full command here.

```
 tr -sc 'A-Z' 'a-z'  < *.txt | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n'  | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

Otherwise below is explanation of every part.

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' < filename.txt
```

This command take filename.txt change every word , essentially you add new line after every word.

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' < *.txt
```

Same as above but all txt files in your directory.

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' < *.txt | sort
```

Pipe your command to sort. First will start with a lot of "a" word.

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' < *.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Pipe sort result to uniq command and count it.

```
tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n' < *.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

Pipe your command again sort to see most used , that most Common words.

Problem here:'and' and 'And' counted twice

```
tr -sc 'A-Z' 'a-z'  < *.txt | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n'  | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

or

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < *.txt | tr -sc 'A-Za-z' '\n'  | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

Change all your words to lowercase and same pipe again. This will get you most common words in your files.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I looked into all 3 answers but this is a very simple and elegant way to do it. I also realized I could not normalize due to the requirements of my problem so this is exactly what I need. How do I remove individual letters from my output or instead just remove apostrophe-s's? Is there a guide to additional tr commands? Thx!

Comment: Yes video link also gives how to remove apostrophe-s's. I will update answer when I have time to watch it.

Comment: Thanks, I meant since apostrophes are removed, I also get individual letters as results, I wanted to exclude those and perhaps treat Marty and Marty's as the same word. It's not explained in the video, but don't worry about responding, this current approach is more than enough for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

GATE(General Architecture of Text Engineering) is a helpful tool here.

Making annotations and composing phrases with Annotations over corpus via GUI tool and then run the Java Annotation Patterns Engine (JAPE) is highly helpful for this.

http://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch8.html#chap:jape

and

http://gate.ac.uk/sale/thakker-jape-tutorial/GATE%20JAPE%20manual.pdf

or

http://gate.ac.uk

are helpful links which you can view.

We have experienced our Signs & Symptoms extraction system from medical corpus using help of this tool in one of our applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NLP is certainly not easy and perhaps not really required in this particular case. With regards to normalisation, perhaps [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) would be sufficient?

Answer (score -1):

You can find links to some useful R packages here:

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html